# Would it be possible to identify the IC from this image (18507CT)?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, identification, debugging, repair

Can someone recognise the IC from this image, or the make based on the font or naming convention used?

[image]

The top reads ***F1823*** towards the end
The bottom reads ***18507CT***. Tried looking up these numbers on Google but none of the results correlate.

This IC is inside [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HFQQ0VU) device. It's a water flosser that has a motor controlled by a two modes and a speed function. More pictures of the PCB [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuJ6b.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I search for `F1823 datasheet` I get this link:

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/40001413e.pdf

14 pins version of PIC F1823: 8/14-Pin Flash Microcontrollers with XLP Technology from MicroChip.

The last line on an IC (in this case 18507CT) is normally the batch number, which is not useful for datasheet searching.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that one before posting but I wasn't sure if it correlates in terms of function requirements for this IC. Further I did not see 18507CT probably a specific variant. I was also not sure if Microchip usually use any convention like the 18507CT at the bottom of the IC. Thought of asking around before trying to replace it

Comment: Do you have a guess on the package used in the image? I'm confused between SOIC and TSSOP as they look identical

Comment: I'm sure there's a convention (within Microchip) about batch numbering.

Comment: If you look in the datasheet on page 420 it should have a term (Package) that shows the type (SL or SN for SOIC, ST for SOP). I always have problems identifying them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The CT probably indicates the package type but unfortunately it's not matching with any of the types indicated on the Microchip datasheet. I'm thinking if it could be a different manufacturer or IC now. Will look around again! Thanks

Comment: Ok … every IC has a logo showing the brand, and there are lists of IC manufacturers logos so you can compare them to find the brand.

Comment: This [link](https://www.digikey.in/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/PIC16F1823T-I-SL/PIC16F1823T-I-SLCT-ND/5013543) is promising. The CT probably means Cut Tape

Comment: I just realised that even if this is the correct part I wouldn't be able to replace it directly because it has an internal flash which probably was programmed before installation in the device

Comment: Closer examination with the clues from the data sheet revealed the exact part number. It's a Microchip PIC16LF1823 -I/SL 18507CT (Batch number as indicated)

Comment: Yes the flash content could be a problem … sometimes I think the flash can be protected, not able to read it out, but even if it is unprotected, it might be a 'project' to make a circuit to get the info out and copy it to another.

Comment: At this point, I'm keeping my fingers crossed and hoping there's an external flash on the same PCB in one of those SMT components. Plan is to study the datasheet and understand pins to see if it interfaces with a flash.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105718/discussion-between-michel-keijzers-and-rs747).